# Is it possible to modify a printed string without printing it again?

Tags: c, string

Here's the deal, imagine I print a string, for example "Hello, world". Is it possible to change only one character without printing the whole thing again? (Just erase one character and printing it in the spot).
So if i want to change the 'o' for a 'p', the cmd prompt would erase the 'o' and printing the 'p' in its place: "Hellp, world".

Comment: Yes it's possible, but depends a *lot* on your operating system and terminal program. Considering you mention "CMD" (as in the Windows command line interface, the old "DOS prompt") take alook at the [Windows console functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/console-functions).

Comment: Windows: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conio.h Linux: https://pl.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ncurses

Comment: Call `printf( "\rHellp" );` if new line `\n` is not already sent and carriage is still at the same line.

Answer (score 2):

On most terminals I’ve used (VT 200, xterm, etc.), assuming you haven’t printed a linefeed (`'\n'`) or a formfeed (`'\f'`), you can print a series of backspace characters (`'\b'`) to back up to the desired location and print the new character.

Obviously, this won’t work on a hardcopy terminal (if any still exist), and it may not behave as expected in some terminal modes.

Comment: Formfeed is `\f`?

Comment: @Bathsheba: =sigh= Typing on an iPad while lying in bed.  Will fix.

Answer (score 1):

no, it's impossible to change an already printed string.
However you can try overriding it with a new string that contains the relevant change by printing again with "\r" at the beginning.